# How to restrict number of fraction digits when parsing number from string?

Tags: objective-c, uikit, nsnumberformatter

I want to restrict the number of fraction digits a user is allowed to enter into a `UITextField` that only accepts (localized) numeric input.

Example with 4 fraction digits allowed:

- Good: `42`, `10.123`, `12345.2345`
- Bad: `0.123456`, `6.54321`

Right now, I'm using `NSNumberFormatter`'s `numberFromString:` in the `UITextField` delegate's `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` to determine whether it's a legal numeric value.

Unfortunately, `NSNumberFormatter` seems to ignore `maximumFractionDigits` in `numberFromString:`. In tests using `getObjectValue:forString:range:error:` I had the same problem, and `range` also was the full length of the string afterwards (unless I start entering letters; then `range` indicates only the part of the string with digits):

```
NSNumberFormatter* formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 3;
formatter.roundingMode = NSNumberFormatterRoundHalfUp;
formatter.generatesDecimalNumbers = YES;
NSDecimalNumber* n = (NSDecimalNumber*)[formatter numberFromString:@"10.12345"];
NSLog(@"Number: %@", n.description); // expected: 10.123, but is: 10.12345
```

How to best restrict the number of fraction digits in user input?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this, but the easiest is probably to split the string into two parts (you will have to localize the '.') and check the length of the second part, like this:

```
- (BOOL)LNNumberIsValid:(NSString *)string
{
    NSArray *numArray = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
    if ([numArray count] == 2)
        if ([[numArray objectAtIndex:1] length] > 4)
            return NO;

    return YES;
}

// Tests
NSLog(@"42: %i", [self LNNumberIsValid:@"42"]); // 1
NSLog(@"10.123: %i", [self LNNumberIsValid:@"10.123"]); // 1
NSLog(@"12345.2345: %i", [self LNNumberIsValid:@"12345.2345"]); // 1

NSLog(@"0.123456: %i", [self LNNumberIsValid:@"0.123456"]); // 0
NSLog(@"6.54321: %i", [self LNNumberIsValid:@"6.54321"]); // 0
```

**EDIT:**
The problem with the code that you added to your question is that you are printing the `description` of the NSDecimalNumber, which is not localized or limited to the number of digits.  The NSDecimalNumber itself stores everything that you give it, so you need to change the original string (like my example above) if you want to change that.  However, once you have your NSDecimalNumber, you can use the same number formatter to convert it back to a string in the format that you like:

```
NSNumberFormatter* formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 3;
formatter.roundingMode = NSNumberFormatterRoundHalfUp;
formatter.generatesDecimalNumbers = YES;
NSDecimalNumber* n = (NSDecimalNumber*)[formatter numberFromString:@"10.12345"];
NSString *s = [formatter stringFromNumber:n];
NSLog(@"Number: %@", s); // expected: 10.123, and is: 10.123
```

Comment: So basically having to do this myself. That's disappointing. I didn't want to do this so far because number formats can be weird -- I'll have to look up international number formats to see whether some of them are unexpectedly weird after the decimal separator. They sure are before it...

Comment: Yes, some of them are.  :-)  maximumFractionDigits should work though, post your code and we can take a look at it.

Comment: Did you set usesSignificantDigits to true (and setRoundingMode should be set also, so that you get the rounding behavior that you expect).

Comment: It's really basic, I edited the question. I found one or two other questions on SO yesterday that also mentioned that this gets ignored when reading numbers from strings, contrary to what the docs seem to indicate.

Comment: That should work by adding `formatter.usersSignificantDigits = YES;` before you call `numberFromString`.  Also, you probably don't want to set `generatesDecimalNumbers` to YES (unless you want it to return NSDecimalNumbers)....

Comment: Unfortunately not. I set `usesSignificantDigits = YES`, and all three `maximum*Digits` to `3`, and the result is still exact when reading `@"10101.12345"`. `generatesDecimalNumbers` doesn't change the outcome.

Comment: Now that I have looked at your code more closely, I see the problem and have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update. That last point is similar to ddevaz's answer (and my comment to it), as I actually want to get a number at the end (and only used `description` to show that the number wasn't shortened as expected): I can solve this via a round-trip to a formatted number string (*user input → number → formatted number string → number with fewer digits*).

Comment: Well, the main point is that you should always use a number formatter when showing a number to the user, so it *really doesn't matter* how it is stored internally.  Using methods like description, or anything that isn't using a properly localized formatter, shouldn't be done if you are going to show the resulting string to the user.  So in this case, whether it is *stored* with excess decimal places or not makes no difference when you properly format it to display to the user at a later time anyway (and makes the "round trip" unnecessary).

Answer (score 1):

after you get the unrestricted number, you can use stringWithFormat on that number to create a string with a certain number of decimal places.

eg.

```
double number = myTextField.text.doubleValue;
NSString *restrictedString =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.4f", number];
```

Comment: Two things:  1) He is using a NSString, and not a float (since it is coming from a text field).  2) You shouldn't be creating strings from floats that represent user input anyway because of the imprecision of storing floats.

Comment: I didn't assume he is getting a float directly. I'm calling floatValue on the text property of the UITextField.

Comment: Unfortunately, `.floatValue` isn't localized. Doing a round-trip via a formatted strings looks interesting though.

Comment: True, sorry I missed that.  However, point 2 is still valid and will give incorrect results.  Use a double instead, and that will help.

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this is by checking the position of the decimal separator and making sure that the insertion either is before that position or the insertion would not exceed the maximum number of fraction digits. 
Also, I check that the input of a new separator does not occur at a place that would lead to more then the allowed fraction digits and that not more than one separators can be inserted

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
NSString *separator = self.numberFormatter.decimalSeparator;

if(string.length == 0) {
    // Empty String means deletion, always possible
    return YES;
}

// Check for valid characters (0123456789 + decimal Separator)
for (int i = 0; i < [string length]; ++i) {
    unichar c = [string characterAtIndex:i];
    if (![self.legalCharSet characterIsMember:c])
    {
        return NO;
    }
}

// Checks if input is separator
if([string isEqualToString:separator]) {
    // Check that separator insertion would not lead to more than 2 fraction digits and that not more than one separators are inserted
// (the MIN() makes sure that length - kMaxFractionDigits won’t be below 0 as length and location are NSUIntegers)
    return range.location >= self.valueField.text.length - MIN(self.valueField.text.length,kMaxFractionDigits) && [self.valueField.text containsString:separator] == NO;
} else {
    // Check if a separator is already included in the string
    NSRange separatorPos = [self.valueField.text rangeOfString: separator];
    if(separatorPos.location != NSNotFound) {
        // Make sure that either the input is before the decimal separator or that the fraction digits would not exceed the maximum fraction digits.
        NSInteger fractionDigits = self.valueField.text.length - (separatorPos.location + 1);
        return fractionDigits + string.length <= kMaxFractionDigits || range.location <= separatorPos.location;
    }
}

return YES;
}
```

The method may not be bullet proof but it should be sufficient for common text insertions.